# setState updating state but not rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react function to handle a form submit

```
  handleSubmit(e){
    this.setState({size: this.state.value});
    this.setState({maze : <Maze size={this.state.value}></Maze>}, () => this.forceUpdate());
    console.log('set state finished');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

in the app class which has the following

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Size: </label>
          <input type="number" min="3" step="1" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}></input>
          <input type="submit" value="Generate Maze"></input>
        </form>
        {this.state.maze}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Yet the code does not rerender the Maze;
2 things to note

I put an alert in the setState callback and it popped up (meaning, I assume, that setState finished and there should have been a rerender) and passed without a rerender

the force update callback doesn't work

How would I fix this?

Complete code of the Main class

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      size : 20,
      value : 20,
      showMaze : false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({maze : <Maze size={this.state.size}></Maze>});
  }

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({value : e.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    this.setState({size: this.state.value});
    this.setState({showMaze: false});
    this.setState({maze : <Maze size={this.state.value}></Maze>}, () => this.forceUpdate());
    this.setState({showMaze: true});
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Size: </label>
          <input type="number" min="3" step="1" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}></input>
          <input type="submit" value="Generate Maze"></input>
        </form>
        {this.state.showMaze? this.state.maze : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

complete code of the Maze class (minus the generation algorithm)

```
class Maze extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      size : this.props.size,
      maze : null
    }; //declare the maze null for now
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.generateMazev2(this.props.size);
  }

  generateMazev2 (size){
    //snippped
  }

  render(){
    var renderMaze = new Array(); //store the table
    //calculate the percentage size of each Cell
    var size = 80.0 / this.props.size; //the table should ideally take up 80% of the page
    if(this.state.maze !== null){
      this.state.maze.forEach(function (row, index, arr){
        var newRow = new Array();
        row.forEach(function (box, theIndex, arr){
          newRow[theIndex] = <Cell size={size} top={box.top} bottom={box.bottom} right={box.right} left={box.left}></Cell>;
        });
        renderMaze[index] = <tr>{newRow}</tr>;
      });
      return (<table>{renderMaze}</table>);
    }else{
      return (<p>Generating</p>);
    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is changing the render() method as below.

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <label>Size: </label>
      <input type="number" min="3" step="1" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}></input>
      <input type="submit" value="Generate Maze"></input>
    </form>
    {this.state.showMaze? <Maze size={this.state.value}></Maze> : null}
  </div>
);
}
```

After that modify handleSubmit() method as below

```
  handleSubmit(e){
    this.setState({size: this.state.value, showMaze: true});
    console.log('set state finished');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

**UPDATE**

It is not a good practice to keep the components as state properties. Hence, replace the `{this.state.showMaze? this.state.maze : null}` line in render method as I've shown.

Further, you need to implement [componentWillReceiveProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) method in the Maze component and modify its state according to new props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   this.setState({size: nextProps.size})
 }
```

Comment: Tried it, no effect

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: You need to implement componentWillReceiveProps() method in Maze component. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way, UI component should not be stored in state value. State should contain only the data.

**Solution:**

Maintain a bool in state variable and use that bool for conditional rendering of Maze component, initial value of bool will be false and update the bool inside `handleSubmit` function.

Like this:

```
handleSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({size: this.state.value, showMazeCom: true});
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>Size: </label>
        <input type="number" min="3" step="1" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Generate Maze"></input>
      </form>
      {this.state.showMazeCom && <Maze size={this.state.value}></Maze>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Update:**

To avoid the unnecessary re-rending of Maze component, use **[shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)** lifecycle method, compare the new and old props values, if they are not same then only allow the re-rendering.

Like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.size != this.props.size)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How do I keep the the maze the same between rerenders (its random algorithm to generate it)?

Comment: you want to do all the calculation only when props values changes, otherwise Maze should not change correct??

Comment: I am trying to do it only when the button is clicked